# Setting image in runtime WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a template in app.xaml. During runtime, i want to create a button and apply this template. I also want to set the Image source during runtime.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="btemp2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Image x:Name="myimage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="84" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="10,-17.5,7,-24.5"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
```

runtime code:

```
Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.Width = 100;
newButton.Height = 50;
newButton.Template = (ControlTemplate)TryFindResource("btemp2");
System.Windows.Controls.Image i = newButton.Template.FindName("myimage",this) as System.Windows.Controls.Image;

Bitmap bmp = GetIconImageFromFile(fileName);
BitmapSource src = GetBitmapImageFromBitmap(bmp);
i.Source = src;
stack.Children.Add(newButton);
```

It does not work as expected.
Breakpoint does not reach

```
Bitmap bmp = GetIconImageFromFile(fileName);
```

Comment: so let us know what is your problem.

Comment: It doesnt work lol. Breakpoint doesnt reach Bitmap bmp = GetIconImageFromFile(fileName);

Comment: Then put it into your question so ppl can read it and directly see what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Binding` to set image. So you should change `ControlTemplate`. In that example we using `Button` `Tag` property to set image `Source`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="btemp2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Image x:Name="myimage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="84" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="10,-17.5,7,-24.5"  Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Tag}"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the `Button` creating code should look like this.

```
Button newButton = new Button();
newButton.Width = 100;
newButton.Height = 50;
newButton.Template = ( ControlTemplate )TryFindResource( "btemp2" );
tempGrid.Children.Add( newButton );
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFTest;component/Images/GPlus.png"));
newButton.Tag = image;
```

Comment: Binding sould be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks so much. Finally works. Is there any recommendation books to read on wpf with c#?

Comment: You're welcome. "Wpf unleashed" is very helpful book.

Comment: In code behind, a [WPF Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) should be created like this: `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFTest;component/Images/GPlus.png")`.

Comment: I also, as no UriKind is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `this` , and use `newButton` in code below, and handle Loaded event :

```
    Grd.Children.Add(newButton);
    newButton.Loaded += newButton_Loaded;
    ...


void newButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = (Image)newButton.Template.FindName("myimage", newButton);
            ...
        }
```

Comment: This will return null insteadof throwing an exception. So still he can't set the source on that.